# How do I use or implement an Android Advertising ID provider?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-advertising-id

I'm working on a minimal test application to acquire a Google Advertising ID using AndroidX libraries. I attempted to follow Google's documentation for retrieving an advertising ID: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/ad-id

However, `AdvertisingIdClient.isAdvertisingIdProviderAvailable()` always returns false, and, as expected, the `onFailure()` method of the future callback gets triggered, with the exception `No compatible AndroidX Advertising ID Provider available.`. I've tested this on 3 phones, 1 of which has a SIM card and carrier (Android 9), and 2 of which don't (Android 9 and 10).

I'm unable to find any documentation on how to acquire or use an "Androidx Advertising ID Provider" to make my minimal example work (i.e. retrieve an Advertising ID that I can see in the debugger or log, even though it isn't used anywhere). Can anyone shed light on resolving this exception?
Here is the code I'm working with. I added a call to `MoreExecutors.directExecutor()` in the call to `addCallback` since Google's code doesn't work as-is (looks like it's out of date).

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val isProviderAvailable: Boolean = AdvertisingIdClient.isAdvertisingIdProviderAvailable(this)
        Log.i("Provider is available: ", isProviderAvailable.toString())
        val x = Runnable { run { determineAdvertisingInfo() } }
        x.run()
    }
    private fun determineAdvertisingInfo() {
        val advertisingIdInfoListenableFuture =
            AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(applicationContext)
        addCallback(
            advertisingIdInfoListenableFuture,
            object : FutureCallback<AdvertisingIdInfo> {
                override fun onSuccess(adInfo: AdvertisingIdInfo?) {
                    val id: String? = adInfo?.id
                    val providerPackageName: String? = adInfo?.providerPackageName
                    val isLimitTrackingEnabled: Boolean? = adInfo?.isLimitAdTrackingEnabled
                }
                override fun onFailure(t: Throwable) {
                    Log.e("=====", "Failed to connect to Advertising ID provider.")
                }
            }, MoreExecutors.directExecutor()
        )
    }
}
```

**gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "redacted"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.ads:ads-identifier:1.0.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.0-android'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.0'
}
```

I'm not committed to Kotlin for this, so if you have a solution in Java, post away.

Comment: If you want to get user advertising id check the following answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61157036/13285588

Comment: Have you found why this occurs? Any solution?

Comment: None. Nothing. I’ve changed jobs twice since I posted this and am not doing Android dev anymore, but I am not convinced that many people know how to do this based on the lack of responses, and the fact that Google’s example code doesn’t work. I wish we had an answer for you.